# Implementing custom loss function in keras with different sizes for y_true and y_pred

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am new to Keras. I need some help in writing a custom loss function in keras with TensorFlow backend for the following loss equation.

[image: Loss function]

The parameters passed to the loss function are :

1. `y_true` would be of shape `(batch_size, N, 2)`. Here, we are passing N `(x, y)` coordinates in each sample in the batch.
2. `y_pred` would be of shape `(batch_size, 256, 256, N)`. Here, we are passing N predicted heatmaps of `256 x 256` pixels in each sample in the batch.

`i` ∈ `[0, 255]`

`j` ∈ `[0, 255]`

`Mn(i, j)` represents value at pixel location `(i, j)` for the n<sup>th</sup> predicted heatmap.

`Mn∼(i, j) = Guassian2D((i, j), y_truen, std)` where

`std = standard deviation`, same standard deviation for both the dimensions (5 px).

y_true<sub>n</sub> is the n<sup>th</sup> (x, y) coordinate. This is the mean.

For details of this, please check the l<sub>2</sub> loss described in this paper
[Human Pose Estimation](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psxab5/human-pose-estimation/).

Note : I mentioned batch_size in shape of y_true and y_pred. I assumed that Keras calls loss function on the entire batch and not on individual samples in the batch. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
def l2_loss(y_true, y_pred):
     loss = 0
     n = y_true.shape[0]
     for j in range(n):
        for i in range(num_joints):
            yv, xv = tf.meshgrid(tf.arange(0, im_height), tf.arange(0, im_width))
            z = np.array([xv, yv]).transpose(1, 2, 0)
            ground = np.exp(-0.5*(((z - y_true[j, i, :])**2).sum(axis=2))/(sigma**2))
            loss = loss + np.sum((ground - y_pred[j,:, :, i])**2)
     return loss/num_joints
```

This is the code I have writen so far. I know that this won't run as we can't use direct numpy ndarrays inside a keras loss function. Also, I need to eliminate loops!

Comment: SO is *not* a code writing service; please show what you have tried so far and the *specific programming* issues you are facing...

Comment: Yeah, I have added my code, please check!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pretty much just translate the numpy functions into Keras backend functions. The only thing to notice is to set up the right broadcast shape.

```py
def l2_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    # set up meshgrid: (height, width, 2)
    meshgrid = K.tf.meshgrid(K.arange(im_height), K.arange(im_width))
    meshgrid = K.cast(K.transpose(K.stack(meshgrid)), K.floatx())

    # set up broadcast shape: (batch_size, height, width, num_joints, 2)
    meshgrid_broadcast = K.expand_dims(K.expand_dims(meshgrid, 0), -2)
    y_true_broadcast = K.expand_dims(K.expand_dims(y_true, 1), 2)
    diff = meshgrid_broadcast - y_true_broadcast

    # compute loss: first sum over (height, width), then take average over num_joints
    ground = K.exp(-0.5 * K.sum(K.square(diff), axis=-1) / sigma ** 2)
    loss = K.sum(K.square(ground - y_pred), axis=[1, 2])
    return K.mean(loss, axis=-1)
```

To verify it:

```py
def l2_loss_numpy(y_true, y_pred):
     loss = 0
     n = y_true.shape[0]
     for j in range(n):
        for i in range(num_joints):
            yv, xv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, im_height), np.arange(0, im_width))
            z = np.stack([xv, yv]).transpose(1, 2, 0)
            ground = np.exp(-0.5*(((z - y_true[j, i, :])**2).sum(axis=2))/(sigma**2))
            loss = loss + np.sum((ground - y_pred[j,:, :, i])**2)
     return loss/num_joints

batch_size = 32
num_joints = 10
sigma = 5
im_width = 256
im_height = 256

y_true = 255 * np.random.rand(batch_size, num_joints, 2)
y_pred = 255 * np.random.rand(batch_size, im_height, im_width, num_joints)

print(l2_loss_numpy(y_true, y_pred))
45448272129.0

print(K.eval(l2_loss_keras(K.variable(y_true), K.variable(y_pred))).sum())
4.5448e+10
```

The number is truncated under the default `dtype` float32. If you run it with `dtype` set to float64:

```py
y_true = 255 * np.random.rand(batch_size, num_joints, 2)
y_pred = 255 * np.random.rand(batch_size, im_height, im_width, num_joints)

print(l2_loss_numpy(y_true, y_pred))
45460126940.6

print(K.eval(l2_loss_keras(K.variable(y_true), K.variable(y_pred))).sum())
45460126940.6
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems that Keras requires `y_true` and `y_pred` to have the same number of dimensions. For example, on the following testing model:

```py
X = np.random.rand(batch_size, 256, 256, 3)
model = Sequential([Dense(10, input_shape=(256, 256, 3))])
model.compile(loss=l2_loss_keras, optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y_true, batch_size=8)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8, 10, 2) for Tensor 'dense_2_target:0', which has shape '(?, ?, ?, ?)'
```

To deal with this problem, you can add a dummy dimension with `expand_dims` before feeding `y_true` into the model:

```py
def l2_loss_keras(y_true, y_pred):
    ...

    y_true_broadcast = K.expand_dims(y_true, 1)  # change this line

    ...

model.fit(X, np.expand_dims(y_true, axis=1), batch_size=8)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the elaborated explanation, you just saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Keras actually support losses with different shapes of `y_pred` and `y_true`. The build in loss `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is an example of this. The TensorFlow implementation of this loss is here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/0fc33feb5f4efe3bb823c57a8390f52932a966ab/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3570

Notice how it says `target: An integer tensor.` and not `` target: A tensor of the same shape as `output`. `` like the others. I tried with a custom loss I made myself and it seems to work fine.

I'm using Keras 2.2.4.

Comment: This way of solving the problem does not generalize since you are not always going to use so called sparse_categorical_crossentropy.

Comment: I never suggested using that specific loss function! Why would you think that? The problem is solved by Keras having support for different shapes of `y_true` and `y_pred` now. This is not limited to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, it is merely one example.

Answer (score 0):

Yu's answer is correct still I want to share my experience. Whenever you want to write custom loss function, beware of certain things:

1. At compile time, Keras will not complain about size mismatch. For example, if `y_pred` which comes from the output layer of your model has 3-D shape, `y_true` will default to 3-D shape. BUT, at run time i.e. during `fit`, if you pass target data as 2-D which many people do, you might end up getting the error in your loss function. E.g., if you are calculating `sigmoid_crossentropy_with_logits`, it will complain. Hence, do pass targets as 3-D via np.expand_dims.
2. Also, in custom loss make sure you use `y_true` and `y_pred` as arguments (if somebody knows that we can use any other names as arguments, pl shout).