# What does y_true and y_pred in Keras contain?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to implement a custom loss function, I read the following links

- [Implementing custom loss function in keras with different sizes for y_true and y_pred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719448/implementing-custom-loss-function-in-keras-with-different-sizes-for-y-true-and-y-pred)
- [What is y_true and y_pred when creating a custom metric in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46663013/what-is-y-true-and-y-pred-when-creating-a-custom-metric-in-keras)

But when I return the following in the metric function

> K.sum(y_true)

it returns a float value.

My label values are all integrals, so why is their sum coming as float value?

Comment: They are probably being cast to floats somewhere, as neural networks take floating point numbers as inputs.

Comment: But all my labels are integer value: 1, 0

Comment: Yes, but keras probably cast them. So you're label 1 will give 1.0 and 0 will give 0.0

Comment: The loss is a continuous value in the end, so at some point they will be cast to float.

Comment: Oh okay. But even if it is 1.0 and 0.0 how can their sum be 983.1287?

Comment: Have you tried printing np.sum(y) where y is your training data set?  If your training data are all integers, this should be an integer.  I'd recommend including a small subset of your training labels (y values) in the question.  You should also describe in more detail the network architecture (easiest just to include the code).