# design a custom loss function in Keras (on the element index in tensors in Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Original question**

I am trying to design a custom loss function in Keras. The target loss function is similar to the "mean_squared_error" in Kears and it presented below.

y_true and y_pred have the shape of [batch_size, system_size], and system_size is an integer, e.g. system_size = 5. The elements in y_true and y_pred are within in the region of [-1, 1]. Before calculating the loss, I need to change the sign of the y_pred for each sample according to the sign of the maximum absolute value of y_true and the corresponding value in y_pred. **For each sample, I need to pick the index of the maximum absolute value first (assume the index is i). If y_pred[:,i] has the same sign as y_true[:,i], then the loss is the normal "mean_squared_error". If the sign of y_pred[:,i] has the different sign as y_true[:,i], all the elements of this sample in y_pred are multiplied by -1.**

I tried following function to define the loss. However it does not work.

```
def normalized_mse(y_true, y_pred):

    y_pred = K.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis = -1) # normalize the y_pred

    loss_minus = K.square(y_true - y_pred)
    loss_plus = K.square(y_true + y_pred) 

    loss = K.mean(tf.where(tf.greater(
                            tf.div(y_true[:, K.argmax(K.abs(y_true), axis = -1))],
                            y_pred[:, K.argmax(K.abs(y_true), axis = -1))]), 0), 
                       loss_minus, loss_plus), axis = -1)

    return loss
```

If I replace the "K.argmax(K.abs(y_true), axis = -1))" with an integer, then the function works well. It seems that this command to pick the index of the maximum absolute value in y_pred is problematic.

Have you ever encountered such problems? Could you please give me some advice and guidance on this problem?

Thank you very much.

Elvin

**Solved**

Thanks to the guidance from @AnnaKrogager, the problem has been solved. As has been pointed out below, K.argmax returns a tensor instead of an integer. According to @AnnaKrogager's answer, I revised the loss function to

```
def normalized_mse(y_true, y_pred):

    y_pred = K.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis = -1)
    y_true = K.l2_normalize(y_true, axis = -1)

    loss_minus = K.square(y_pred - y_true)
    loss_plus = K.square(y_pred + y_true)

    index = K.argmax(K.abs(y_true), axis = -1)
    y_true_slice = tf.diag_part(tf.gather(y_true, index, axis = 1))
    y_pred_slice = tf.diag_part(tf.gather(y_pred, index, axis = 1))

    loss = K.mean(tf.where(tf.greater(tf.div(y_true_slice, y_pred_slice), 0), 
                       loss_minus, loss_plus), axis = -1)

    return loss
```

In order to verify it, I define another function with numpy

```
def normalized_mse_numpy(y_true, y_pred):
    import operator

    batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
    sample_size = y_true.shape[1]
    loss = np.zeros((batch_size))

    for i in range(batch_size):
        index = np.argmax(abs(y_true[i, :]))
        y_pred[i, :] = y_pred[i, :]/linalg.norm(y_pred[i, :])
        y_true[i, :] = y_true[i, :]/linalg.norm(y_true[i, :])

        sign_flag = y_true[i, index] / y_pred[i, index]
        if sign_flag < 0:
           for j in range(sample_size):
               loss[i] = loss[i] + (y_true[i, j] + y_pred[i, j])**2
        else:
           for j in range(sample_size):
               loss[i] = loss[i] + (y_true[i, j] - y_pred[i, j])**2

        loss[i] = loss[i] / SystemSize

     return loss

SystemSize = 5
batch_size = 10
sample_size = 5
y_true = 100 * np.random.rand(batch_size, sample_size)
y_pred = 100 * np.random.rand(batch_size, sample_size)

numpy_result = normalized_mse_numpy(y_true, y_pred)
keras_result = K.eval(normalized_mse(K.variable(y_true), K.variable(y_pred)))

print(numpy_result.sum())
0.9979743490342015

print(keras_result.sum())
0.9979742

numpy_result - keras_result
array([ 4.57889131e-08,  1.27995520e-08,  5.66398740e-09,  1.07868497e-08,
    4.41975839e-09,  7.89889471e-09,  6.68819598e-09,  1.05113101e-08,
   -9.91241045e-09, -1.20345756e-09])
```

I also benefit from the answer by Yu-Yang in [Implementing custom loss function in keras with different sizes for y_true and y_pred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719448/implementing-custom-loss-function-in-keras-with-different-sizes-for-y-true-and-y).

Please be noted that tf.gather() does not support 'axis' in some early-version tensorflow, e.g, 1.0.1. It works in 1.11.0. If the tensorflow version is low, you may get the error of ["gather() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"](https://github.com/singlasahil14/sortpool2d/issues/1).

Comment: And the other indices?

Comment: Can you confirm the datatype of "K.argmax(K.abs(y_pred), axis = -1))"?

Comment: Perhaps K.argmax(K.abs(y_pred), axis = -1)) yields a list rather an integer due to duplicates of the max value, just confirm the data type an go from there

Comment: It yields a tensor.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Instead of an integer, K.argmax returns a tensor. According to the answer from @AnnaKrogager, this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `K.argmax(K.abs(y_pred), axis = -1))` is a tensor, not an integer, and therefore slicing doesn't work. You can instead use `tf.gather` to do the slicing:

```
index = K.argmax(K.abs(y_true), axis = -1)
y_true_slice = tf.diag_part(tf.gather(y, index, axis=1))
```

This is equivalent to `y_true[:,index]`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What you suggested works well and the problem has been solved. I have added the revised loss function with its validation test to the post. Thank you very much for your help.